# mysql replication duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, replication

I replicate my mysql master to a slave. They works very well but once in a while, duplicate entry would happen and I don't know how to resolve it ending up copy the master over and start replicate again which costs me a lot of time.

This is the `show slave status\G` :

```
.....
Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000139
Relay_Log_Pos: 12476407
....
Last_SQL_Errno: 1062
Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry '573026' for key 'PRIMARY' .....
```

I use `mysqlbinlog` to show contents of `mysql-relay-bin.000139` :

```
# at 12476407
.... SET TIMESTAMP=1636678470/*!*/;
....
# at 12476445
#211112  8:54:30 server id 1  end_log_pos 12476475  Query   thread_id=9 exec_time=0  
error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1636678470/*!*/;
INSERT INTO ..... (ID, ......) VALUES (573026, .....)
# at 12476664
.... SET TIMESTAMP=1636678470/*!*/;
....
# at 12476734
.... SET TIMESTAMP=1636678472/*!*/;
....
# at 12476772
#211112  8:54:32 server id 1  end_log_pos 12476801  Query   thread_id=9 exec_time=0  
error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1636678472/*!*/;
INSERT INTO .... (ID, ....) VALUES (573027, ....)
....
```

Then I check `select * from .... where id=57326;` and the record exists so it is a real duplication though I don't know why. After searching the web I tried to skip that duplicated record from the relay by:

```
stop slave;
set global sql_slave_skip_counter = 1;
start slave;
```

It did skipped the problem record. But then the replicate stops at the next `INSERT`:

```
Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000139
Relay_Log_Pos: 12476734
....
Last_Errno: 1062
Last_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry '573027' for key 'PRIMA ....
....
```

This time `select * from .... where id=573027;` gets nothing, so it is not really duplication. Appreciate any ideas how I can resolve this without copying the master over again. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How exactly did you create the replica? Are you inserting onto the slave using another application? If unsure, have you set read_only on the slave to prevent this?

Comment: Is the Replica set to `readonly=ON`; it should be.

Comment: No, I only use mysql to sync master's updates to slave. No, the slave is not readonly. But I am sure no other software is updating the slave.

Comment: One thing may be relevant. The slave machine encountered BOSD recently but I have no way to check if the time coincident with the replication failure. Ever if it is so, the skip method should be able to skip the first duplication, and cannot explain the reason of the second duplication.

Comment: Row based or statement based replication is used?

Comment: Mind is 5.7.21 and I didn't set any binlog format, so I think the default is row-based.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason for this issue appearing was a clock skew on the replication server and its correction:

The rows causing the "duplicate entry" error were created by an event that uses the current server time. The clock on the replication server had been ahead. After it was corrected the event tried to create rows with timestamps that already existed.

Comment: Just eondering. If you have server time sensitive data, hiw does the duplicate dara help you?